# Is there a simpler method to storage data for chrome apps

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have been trying to find a simple solution(like HTML5 localstorage) to store data for a Chrome app.
I see they have complex storing mechanism @ http://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage.html but I hate this method because retrieving data is asynchronous. To retrieve data I have todo something like.

```
chrome.storage.local.get(key,function(data){console.log(data)});
```

I hate this method because I cannot assign a variable in a simple manner.

Chrome packaged apps do not support window.localStorage.setItem(); window.localStorage.getItem();
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Javascript. Rather than fight asynchronicity, you must eventually embrace it. Look at using promises as an alternative to callbacks.

Comment: It is really tedious to use `chrome.storage.local` I could use global variable as a last resort but I was there was a better option.

Comment: It is not tedious after you get used to it :) I used to think likewise when I first came face to face **chrome.storage**. The truth is though, that once you get used to it (and probably undergo a non-trivial app refactoring to adapt to an asynchronous model), you'll find out it is cool, fast and its the future :) Seriously, embrace asynchronicity (as pinoyyid put it) ! And keep in mind, global variables do not provide the same functionality (it doesn't mean they are not sufficient for the task at hand).

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using `sessionStorage` since the `localStorage` is disabled

Answer (score -1):

Whilst its probably not a best practice, you could use

```
localStorage.setItem('test', 'value');
localStorage.getItem('test'); // == value
```

Just be careful if storing objects in localStorage - youd need to JSON encode them first.

Comment: unfortunately it's not supported in Chrome packaged apps.

Comment: Apologies. I knew it worked in extensions but obviously not apps.